# PHP RSS get and display title of multiple RSS channels

Tags: php, codeigniter, rss

I have following code:

```
        $rss[] = $this->rssparser->set_feed_url('someUrl')->set_cache_life(30)->getFeed(4);
        $rss[] = $this->rssparser->set_feed_url('someURL')->set_cache_life(30)->getFeed(3);
        $rss[] = $this->rssparser->set_feed_url('someURL')->set_cache_life(30)->getFeed(5);
```

Each one of them are being displayed in different `div`s and what I want is that the title of the related channel gets displayed in the related `div`.

So far I have:

```
foreach ($rss as $feed)
{
    $channel = $this->rssparser->channel_data['title'];

    $result = "<div class='rssFeed'>";
    $result .= '<h3>'.$channel.'</h3>';

    foreach ($feed as $item)
         {  
        $result .= '<div class="rssContent">
            <a href="'.$item['link'].'">'.$item['title'].'</a>
            <br />
            <span>'.$item['pubDate'].'</span>
            </div>
            ';
        }
            $result .= '</div>';

            echo $result;

        }
```

but that only displays the title from the last channel of the array in the top...

does anyone have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the channel title before getting the next feed. For example: -

```
<?php
class Controller
{
    public function action()
    {
        $feeds = array(
            array('url' => 'http://example.org/feed.rss', 'count' => 3),
            array('url' => 'http://example.org/feed.rss', 'count' => 4),
            array('url' => 'http://example.org/feed.rss', 'count' => 5),
        );

        $rss = array();

        foreach ($feeds as $feed) {
            $rss[] = array(
                'items' => $this->rssparser->set_feed_url($feed['url'])->set_cache_life(30)->getFeed($feed['count']),
                'title' => $this->rssparser->channel_data['title'],
            );
            $this->rssparser->clear();
        }
    }
}
```

You would then iterate over the feed like so: -

```
<?php foreach ($rss as $feed): ?>
    <h1><?php echo $feed['title']; ?></h1>
    <?php foreach ($feed['items'] as $item): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $item['link']; ?>">
            <?php echo $item['title']; ?>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```